# Text color for DataGridView control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I had several controls that had the `ForeColor` property set to `"Active Color Text"` instead of `"Black"`. This made the text appear white on certain machines, and black on other computers.

I have the same problem with my `DataGridView` control, but this does not have a text color property. How can I make the data text always appear black?

Comment: Set it to "Black"? :\

Comment: Set WHAT to black? There is no text color property for that control.

Comment: Actually [there is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx). But its `BrowsableAttribute` is set to `false` and it doesn't show up in the Properties tab in the designer. So you change it in code: `dataGridView1.ForeColor = Color.Black;`.

Comment: Also, I apologize for the snarkiness of my earlier comment. At a glance it appeared as though you had answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

If you view Properties of your DataGridView, you should see:

- DefaultCellStyle
- ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle.

Clicking the ellipsis for either will bring up a property window where you can set the looks of the data in your control.

[image]

Comment: Changing those properties didn't fix the problem, and the ForeColor keeps changing itself back to ActiveCaptionText after I build. The property I was after apparently doesn't show up in the Properties tab (see Bryans answer  above).

Comment: 2 questions.  
  1. You are just talking font color of just the data grid correct? 
  2.  Are you anywhere in the code setting DataGridView = New DataGridView?

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to set the font color of the data grid. No, I am not setting it to new (except where it gets set in the designer).

Comment: Just so i have this right... You open the property window, change the DefaultCellStyle using the CellStyleBuilder, click ok, click build, reopen the CellStyleBuilder and your changes are gone?!